# Ant script execute svn to set svn:externals doesn't work

Tags: svn, ant, tortoisesvn, svn-externals, svn-propset

In Ant's build.xml, I use Ant's exec task to call svn with the args like this:

```
 <exec executable="svn" outputproperty="svnoutput" output="D:\log.txt">
    <arg line="ps svn:externals . -F E:\Dailybuild\${client_path}\text.txt"/>
 </exec>
```

And what in my text.txt file is:

```
 Res\Txt https://raphaelchen-pc1.****.com:8443/svn/QQSG_Resource/trunk
```

When I build my project with this build.xml, the output log shows:

```
 property 'svn:externals' set on '.'
```

It seems that I have set svn:externals to **The path("Res\Txt")** successfully,

but when I use **TortoiseSvn** to check whether this set works, there is **nothing** happened.

there is no property been set in my work copy.

Maybe the **path(Res\Txt)** int text.txt is not right?

Because when I use **Windows's cmd** to set this property, it succeed.

First I go to my **work copy's directory**(E:\Dailybuild\deployForDelta)

and execute svn ps command:

```
 svn ps svn:externals . -F E:\Dailybuild\deployForDelta\text.txt
```

Then use Tortoise SVN to check the results and find the property has been set.

Why the action in script does not work? Anyone can help me?

Comment: what is in log.txt?  what is the value of outputproperty? I suspect your svn command is failing.  You'll want to add failonerror="true" to your exec task.

Having said that... what are you actually doing?  I find it usually bad to mix the build and the source control - particularly what you're doing (actually changing source).  Does ant actually check it in too?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Is the current directory (`.`) the svn working copy directory that you need to set a property to?

Maybe you need to add `dir="${PATH_TO_YOUR_SVN_WORKING_COPY}"` to the `<exec>` task.

Comment: thank u. the directory to be set is wrong and I confused how to solve this problem.